# Using more than two wide characters in swprintf causes a crash?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, atl

The following piece of code causes a crash

"Unhandled exception at 0x01C006AB in ASMaplePro.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x003A0043"

```
TCHAR text[512]={0},text2[256]={0};
char text1[128]={0};   
strcpy(text1,_T("how are you");
wcscpy(text2,_T(" Bob?"));
swprintf(text,_T("%s\\%s"),(CA2W)text1,text2);
```

I suspect its because I'm using both 'text' and 'list' which are taken as wide character buffers in one go!

But can someone tell me why exactly the crash is caused.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, let alone cause a crash.

Comment: Does this code even compile? `strcpy` takes a `const char*` and `wcscpy` takes a `const wchar_t*` and `_T` translates to one or the other. NOT both.

Comment: You have errors everywhere. I also get errors that _T and CA2W are undefined, yet I'm including windows.h.

Comment: @Archimaredes `_T` can be found in `tchar.h` and `CA2W` is part of the ATL.

Comment: Well its working for me!!

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use `TCHAR`, as mentioned in comment this could mean either ANSI `char` or UTF16 `whar_t`, depending on wether or not `UNICODE` was defined. `TCHAR` is useless at best, unless you are targeting Windows 98.

The `T()` thing can be confusing too, again it could mean either ANSI or Unicode. Instead use the `L` prefix for Unicode strings.

The second argument in `swprintf` should be buffer maximum size:

```
char ansi[128] = { 0 };
wchar_t unicode[256] = { 0 };
wchar_t unicode2[128] = { 0 };

strcpy(ansi, "how are you");
wcscpy(unicode, L" Bob?");

wcscpy(unicode2, CA2W(ansi));

wchar_t result[512];
swprintf(result, 512, L"%s %s", unicode, unicode2);
```

Comment: Is it mandatory that I should copy ansi-x-unicode2 and then use it? Whats wrong with using swprintf(result, 512, L"%s %s", unicode,(CA2W)ansi);?

Comment: Sticking things in to one function makes it more difficult to debug but I guess you can use it that way if you want.

Comment: so right now my statement is like swprintf(result, 512, L"%s %s", (CA2W)ansi, unicode);  But only the characters in ansi is getting appended to result. the characters in unicode is not getting appended to result.

Comment: Yes I just noticed you can use it as `(CA2W)ansi` because it goes through a class which probably has `const wchar_t*` operator.

Comment: Now its working. I just did this swprintf(text,_T("%s\\%s"),(LPCWSTR)(CA2W)text1,text2);